# Create React App in Root Directory and on the "src" folder

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way to specify that create react app to not create src folder, rather I want the files to stay at root directory so I can work on my project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, there is no way.

From the documentation about the [folder structure](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure/)

> For the project to build, these files **must exist** with exact filenames:
>
> - `public/index.html` is the page template;
> - `src/index.js` is the JavaScript entry point.

Even if you try to use a [custom template](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/custom-templates#building-a-template), it requires `src/index.js` or `src/index.tsx` files to exist

There are two possible solutions you can try:

1. Use [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) and adjust webpack configuration to allow the source code to be in the root folder
2. [Eject](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) create-react-app and re-configure webpack

Comment: For example, next uses root directory, so I don't know how isn't possible in react, where as the next is build on top of react, right?

Comment: Next is not built on top of react, it just uses react as a view library. Both create-react-app and next provide pre-defined webpack configuration for you. In next webpack configuration - you can use `src/index.(t|j)sx` or  `index.(t|j)sx`, whereas create-react-app configures webpack in the way where you are restricted to use `src/index.(t|j)sx` only

Comment: Thank you, So can I use then next same as react? for example as Spa, the next generates pages for each of them

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by "use then next same as react". But, if you mean "can I create SPA with next" - the answer is "yes, you can do that"